# Activity method gets call before oncreate in android from the other class

Tags: android

I have a scenario where I have created library project in which I am loading the layout as well defining the method which I want to call from the Application project.

```
public class LibraryActivity {


public LibraryActivity() {

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.barchart_layout);
    bindViews();

}


   public void bindViews() {

        bChart = (BarChart)findViewById(R.id.barchart);
}

   public  void setData(int count, float range) {

   //definition of the method
  // I have to user bChart view here 
  System.out.println("part 1 "+bChart); <---- this is null
}
```

Now I have successfully created the AAR project and I want to use this setData from the other project.
So when I run this From the other project By using below code

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LibraryActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);

            LibraryActivity barChartCallBack = new LibraryActivity();
            LibraryActivity.setData(15,25);
```

**I got the null pointer on the** **bChart** because my method setData got call first before oncreate so **findviewbyid** gives me **null** for the **bChart**.

Comment: Pass that data via `Bundle`.

Comment: SetData method have the view which has to load before this method gets call I am able to pass the data but because view is not loading and method gets call first so i am getting null pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the data on a completely different LibraryActivity object. First you tell the system with the intent to start one, then you start another one that does not get displayed, but you use it to call setData.

Read up on the android developer site:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Basically you need to pass the data via extras in with the intent.

Comment: I know that but my problem here is the method which i have in library class getting call first [because I am calling this method from the other project] and oncreate is loading after that because of that i am not able to get the view which I have to use in setData method.

Comment: Do not call setData from outside, use in.putExtra(...) instead